# SSO / SAML session timeout after 2 min Rails/AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, single-sign-on, saml

- SSO session expires after 2min.
- devise config.timeout_in set to 15min.
- user tokens are valid for 15min.
- user and server clock are in sync.

But still, SSO users get kicked out after 2 min of an idle state. Any idea?